# how to check checkbox in dropdownmenu using findElements and get ? (java/seleniumWebDriver)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have: [image]

```
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu js-dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form']/li/div/label/span/span[@class='check']"));
    checkboxes.get(1).click();
```

`Xpath` is ok. Why does `get` not work?

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: @Vladimir Riabokon Do you wants to target city[] checkbox ?

Comment: @Avishek Bhattacharya .I want to choose a checkbox for the specified sequence number  (not by the name of the field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats because you are looking for all the element containing class 'check' in `//ul[@class='dropdown-menu js-dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form']/li/div/label/span/span[@class='check']` and there is just one element. Also, is it your requirement to use List ? I mean you can click on it directly as below: If you want to click on let's say 'Do ustalenia' then,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu js-dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form']/li/div/label/span/span[@class='check']")).click();
```

or you can share more html of your checkboxes. I am making a guess at this:

```
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span/span[@class='check']")); // this will find all span elements with class 'check' inside li/div/label
checkboxes.get(1).click();
```

Comment: if my answer helped then please accept this as an answer. To accept this as an answer click on the check mark beside the answer.